# Google Calendar API Offline Usage with access token in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I am using Ruby Api Client for google calendar. I am making an application in which my server side needs to post on user's calendar every 1 pm. My problem is , how can I access the google calendar API offline. I store the access token in my DB and applying the exact same operation as google has mentioned in their docs.

```
client_opts = JSON.parse(user.credentials)
auth_client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(client_opts)
```

I am getting 'Missing token endpoint URI' error. Please help me with this, its been 5 days and i cant find out how to solve this. I will really appreciate the help.

Comment: you should be storing the refresh token in your database and using the Refresh token to gain a new access token when you need to access their data again.

Comment: I am not having a refresh token thats the point, even though I am setting the access type to offline. Is it with google's new API or something wrong with my code. `{ access_type: "offline",
                    prompt: "consent",
                    select_account: true,
                    scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'] }`